# How can buying an extra flight (different PNR) with another be cheaper than not buying that?

Tags: air-travel, fares

A friend was looking for flights from Lisbon to Delhi and found a curious situation where buying an additional flight with an itinerary is cheaper than buying just that itinerary. The additional flight is a different airline, different PNR and doesn't come up on the other airline website. I am curious as to how does this work for the booking website. Here are the details:

Trip.com showed Lisbon to Delhi flight, with LIS-MAD (Lisbon-Madrid) on Iberia (9th May), then overnight stay in Madrid and MAD-AUH-DEL (Madrid-Abu Dhabi-Delhi) on Etihad (10th May) for €270. It showed it is self transfer in Madrid. This specific itinerary is not showed on any other website but only Trip.

Just out of curiosity, we searched for MAD-DEL on 10th may (the same flight as bundled in the above booking), and that is being shown as €292. On Etihad website, the fare shown is €292.74, which is almost identical to what is shown on Trip. The LIS-MAD flight (9th May) bundled is being shown as €94. So in total it comes out to €386. How is Trip selling it together for €270?

My friend eventually booked the LIS-DEL on Trip and it has two separate PNRs for both the flights. The PNR of Iberia only shows the LIS-MAD booking on the Iberia website and has a luggage allowance of 23 kg, and the PNR of Etihad only shows the MAD-AUH-DEL booking on the Etihad website and has a luggage allowance of 30 kg, both same as the above individual fares quoted.

So someone who wants to buy MAD-AUH-DEL can buy it bundled with an extra LIS-MAD flight for cheaper. (I know that for a lot, the savings are not worth the perceived hassle of booking via a third party, but I am purely talking about the money aspect here)

I am aware that single bookings with extra flights can be cheaper and also aware of hidden city bookings. But this is a totally different case where the two bookings are separate. So it is not a case of a LIS-MAD-AUH-DEL ticket being cheaper than a MAD-AUH-DEL ticket, but buying a LIS-MAD ticket and a MAD-AUH-DEL ticket (on different airlines and PNRs) together being cheaper than just buying the MAD-AUH-DEL ticket.

How does all this work? Is this just a glitch in Trip's system or is there something else behind this?

Comment: Could be a glitch, could be a batch of negotiated bulk fares that they are trying to unload, could be that their revenue model says MAD-DEL people will pay more than LIS-DEL people, ...

Comment: I've given up on applying rational thinking to airline pricing :-)